# Segmentation fault when overloading QDebug::operator<<

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading, qdebug

I tried to overload `QDebug::operator<<` for `std::string`. I know that we can debug (using qDebug()) `std::string` objects using its `std::string::c_str()` function but I want to avoid typing `.c_str` each time.

Here is my attempt

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <string>

inline const QDebug& operator<< (const QDebug& qDebugObj, const std::string& str) {
    return qDebugObj << str.c_str();
}

int main()
{
     std::string s = "4444555";
     qDebug() << s;
}
```

This program produces segmentation fault. What is incorrect with this code?

Here is the stack:

```
#1  0x00000037c407a911 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000037ca8bd09d in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00000037ca89c3c9 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
   from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00000037ca89cde5 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00000037ca89cf33 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00000000004012ca in operator<< (qDebugObj=..., str="4444555") at main.cpp:5
```

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/custom-types.html#making-the-type-printable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [every overloaded output operator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qdebug.html), you will see that *none* have a `const` qualifier. Which is your problem, you try to modify a constant object. Remove the `const` qualification of the `qDebugObject` and the return value.

You should have compiler warnings screaming about it, and if not then you need to enable more warnings (at least use `-Wall` when compiling with GCC/clang).

---

The *actual* problem, as answered by Mike Seymour in a comment, is that your overload will be called recursively until you get a stack overflow.

A way of bypassing that might be to convert the string to something else, like for example a `QString`:

```
return qDebugObj << QString::fromStdString(str);
```

Comment: Why isn't this an error? Without a `const_cast` or equivalent, shouldn't this fail to compile?

Comment: @BoBTFish I thought so too, but as is apparent the OP manages to build without errors.

Comment: After removing `const` I get errors, but after removing `&` too, it works fine.

Comment: @Ashot And you remember to remove `const` from *both* the argument and the return type?

Comment: @BoBTFish, for example, on Windows it fails to compile.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes I removed both. I test it on linux

Comment: @BoBTFish: No, it will convert the result of `c_str` back to `std::string` and call this function recursively, until the stack overflows.

Comment: @MikeSeymour And of course if does! Doh, how could I miss that. :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Now seg fault is clear. What is the correct usage. Without const and apersand?

Comment: Or I should somehow avoid the recursion ?

Comment: @Ashot:  The QT documentation defines how you should overload their output operators in great detail.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/custom-types.html#making-the-type-printable

Comment: @Ashot Added the problem from Mike in my answer (you should really have added an answer yourself Mike!) and a possible solution.

Comment: QString has a `QString::fromStdString(std::string)` which should be used instead of using the c_str from std::string

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your attempt to make an output stream `const`, you also failed to follow the instructions in the [QT documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/custom-types.html#making-the-type-printable)

```
// with the fixed output operator
inline QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg, const std::string& str)
{
    dbg.nospace() << QString::fromStdString(str);
    return dbg.space();
}
```

QT wants the output operator passed by copy (not by reference).  There used to be a reason for that, but I cannot remember what it was.